# Finding the three longest substrings in a string using SPARQL on the Wikidata Query Service, and ranking them across strings

Tags: substring, sparql, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to identify the longest three substrings from a string using SPARQL and the Wikidata Query Service and then rank

- the substrings within a string by length
- the strings by the lengths of any of those longest substrings .

I managed to identify the first and second substring from a string and could of course just create similar additional lines to tackle the problem, but this seems ugly and inefficient, so I am wondering if anyone here knows of a better way to get there.

This is a simplified version of the code, though I have left some auxiliary variables in that I am using for tracking progress on the way. You can try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Ftitle%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22What%20are%20the%20longest%20three%20words%20in%20this%20string%3F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22A%20really%20complicated%20title%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22OneWordTitleInCamelCase%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22Thanks%20for%20your%20help%21%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20BIND%28STRLEN%28REPLACE%28%3Ftitle%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%22%22%29%29%20AS%20%3Ftitlelength%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20BIND%28STRBEFORE%28%3Ftitle%2C%20%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fsubstring1%29%0A%20%20BIND%28STRLEN%28REPLACE%28%3Fsubstring1%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%22%22%29%29%20AS%20%3Fsubstring1length%29%0A%20%20BIND%28STRAFTER%28%3Ftitle%2C%20%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fpostfix%29%0A%20%20BIND%28STRLEN%28REPLACE%28%3Fpostfix%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%22%22%29%29%20AS%20%3Fpostfixlength%29%0A%20%20BIND%28STRBEFORE%28%3Fpostfix%2C%20%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fsubstring2%29%0A%20%20BIND%28STRLEN%28REPLACE%28%3Fsubstring2%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%22%22%29%29%20AS%20%3Fsubstring2length%29%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fsubstring1length%29%20).

Clarification in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162289/finding-the-three-longest-substrings-in-a-string-using-sparql-on-the-wikidata-qu#comment95156299_54162289): if it is necessary to treat this query as a subquery and to feed it with results from another subquery, that's fine with me. To get an idea of the kinds of use I have in mind, see [this demo](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:Daniel_Mietchen/Wikidata_lists/Long_words_in_work_titles).

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  {
    VALUES (?title) {
      ("What are the longest three words in this string?")
      ("A really complicated title")
      ("OneWordTitleInCamelCase")
      ("Thanks for your help!")
    }
  }
  BIND(STRLEN(REPLACE(?title, " ", "")) AS ?titlelength)
  
  BIND(STRBEFORE(?title, " ") AS ?substring1)
  BIND(STRLEN(REPLACE(?substring1, " ", "")) AS ?substring1length)
  BIND(STRAFTER(?title, " ") AS ?postfix)
  BIND(STRLEN(REPLACE(?postfix, " ", "")) AS ?postfixlength)
  BIND(STRBEFORE(?postfix, " ") AS ?substring2)
  BIND(STRLEN(REPLACE(?substring2, " ", "")) AS ?substring2length)
}
ORDER BY DESC(?substring1length)
```

Expected results:

```
longsubstring   substringlength
OneWordTitleInCamelCase 23
complicated 11
longest 7
really  6
string  6
Thanks  6
title   5
three   5
your    4
help    4
```

Actual results:

```
title   titlelength substring1  substring1length    postfix postfixlength   substring2  substring2length
Thanks for your help!   18  Thanks  6   for your help!  12  for 3
What are the longest three words in this string?    40  What    4   are the longest three words in this string? 36  are 3
A really complicated title  23  A   1   really complicated title    22  really  6
OneWordTitleInCamelCase 23      0       0       0
```

Comment: That seems to be impossible with SPARQL. I mean, you'd need some kind of *"explode"* function which does not exist in SPARQL.

Comment: And your substring solution can't work in general, because you'd have to know the number of words per sentence in advance

Comment: Yes, but there could be a subquery before where a regex defines lower and / or upper boundaries on the number of, say, spaces in the string.

Comment: With "subquery" you mean a separate query executed before the current one, right? Because a real subquery won't change anything

Comment: Yes, a separate query before this one, since I plan to use this in Wikidata contexts anyway, so would wrap the Wikidata parts around such subqueries.

Comment: I'd do it in this way: https://paws-public.wmflabs.org/paws-public/User:Luitzen/Stack/Split%20titles.ipynb?kernel_name=python3

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks - I do not understand the role of the URL with "HasWord" but otherwise, this seems to find the three longest substrings in a string, albeit not order them across strings. If SPARQL can't do what I asked for (as the first comment above would suggest), then I'll naturally have to look into other options. The reason I wanted to go with SPARQL only is that this would allow the construction of Listeria lists to work on, which do not require users to know how to code. For examples, see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Source_MetaData/Wikidata_lists .

Comment: If you do not want to "group" words by titles, just remove the inner SELECT. https://paws-public.wmflabs.org/paws-public/User:Luitzen/Stack/Split%20titles%201.ipynb